# Has my textbook got a mistake in it regarding the use of 習う？

Tags: verbs

There is a sentence in my textbook 'The Handbook of Japanese Verbs',

> 私は姉に人形の作り方を習いました

It is translated as 'I learned how to make dolls from my older sister'.

But, I would have thought it means 'I taught my older sister how to make dolls'.

With the former being something like,

> 私は姉から人形の作り方を習ってくれました。

Sorry, I may have mistranslated it. But, more importantly I'm wondering if the original Japanese sentence and translation is mistaken?

Comment: The correct te-form of 習う is 習って.

Answer (score 7):

- 教【おし】える: *to teach*
- 教【おそ】わる: *to be taught*
- 習う: *to learn* (during instruction)

Therefore there is no chance that the sentence means "I taught". Actually your textbook is correct.

Moreover, as 習う is your own action despite suggesting the existence of instructor ("*you* learn" not "*somebody* makes you learn"), the use of ～てくれる or ～てもらう is ungrammatical, because you can only attach them on an action that originates from someone and affects someone else. The same applies to 教わる.

Comment: ahh, thanks I see the mistake in my translation. Still I am wondering, does the original sentence need to be 私は姉から人形の作り方を習いました to mean 'I learned how to make dolls from my older sister', or is the textbook's original sentence and translation correct?

Comment: @SamFranks Yes they're correct and natural.

Comment: OK I see, thanks for that. My understanding of 習う was mistaken!